# Finding $E[X]$ of a probability distribution

Tags: statistics

(In thousands), the number of deaths per year is a random variable with probability distribution $P(X=k)=2/5(3/5)^{k+1}$ for integer $k$. What is the expected number of deaths in a year?

I would usually $E[X] = xp(x)$, taking the sum or integral. But the function given is neither pdf nor cdf and I'm not sure hwt to make of it.

Comment: It is a PMF, although it doesn't look normalized to me. I think the exponent should be $k$ instead of $k+1$, assuming $k\ge 0$.

Comment: I think it is $k+1$. Does that make the answer different?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is neither a pdf nor a CDF but it should be a pmf, a probability mass function of a geometric rv. As noted, the exponent should be

$k$, if $k \in \{0;1;2;\dots\}$

or

$k-1$, if $k \in \{1;2;\dots\}$

Consequently the expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\Sigma_i x_i p(x_i)$$

Thus first verify your correct pmf then solve your sum. The result will be  $\mathbb{E}[X]=3/2$ or $\mathbb{E}[X]=5/2$, respectively .

---

Now let's assume that $k \in \{0;1;2;3;\dots\}$ thus the rv is a geometric with CDF

$$P(X\leq k)=1-0.6^{k+1}$$

Using the definition of expectation (the more suitable definition you can use, obviously) you get that

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} 0.6^{k+1}=0.6\cdot\frac{1}{1-0.6}=1.5$$

It is obvious that if you actually want to calculate the expectation of your pmf, that is with support in $\{-1;0;1;\dots\}$ no calculation are needed, as your random variable is $Y=X-1$ with expectation $1.5-1=0.5$ but it is meaningless, referred to the text of your exercise, as you are modeling the random number of deaths. As per my knowledge only 1 single case of resurrected person happened in the past!

---

[this is for your reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: The exponent is actualy $k+1$. I hope the answer is still attainable - I did try this actually so is the $x$ supposed to be the $k$? I would have $$k(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{3}{5})^{k+1}$$? That is what I am confused about

Comment: I get $$2/5((3/5)^2+2(3/5)^3+3(3/5)^4+...+)$$ I cannot use a GP sum due to the 1,2,3,4...coefficients out front

Comment: @user71207 : the exponent cannot be $k+1$ and there is a specific reason for this. If the exponent actually is $k+1$ this means that the support must be $k \in\{-1;0;1;2\dots\}$ and this support is not suitable to model the numbers of deaths per year. Anyway I will show you how to proceed. Regardeless the text, if you want to calculate the expectation with your exponent $k+1$ the result will be 0.5.

Comment: @user71207 : I edited my answer with a lot of details. Hope now it is clear. Probabily they did a little bit confusion with pmf and CDF of your geometric rv. The correct pmf should be $0.4\cdot 0.6^k$ and the correct CDF is $1-0.6^{k+1}$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the addirtional information its clearer now. However, your $E[X]$ isn't what I expected, is $E[X]$ not $xp(x)$? I see $p(x) = 0.6^{k+1}$ (where did the $0.4$ go?!) and no $x$

Comment: @user71207 : there are several different definitions of expected value calculation. I used a useful definition for non negative rv's: $E(X)=\Sigma[1-F]$. If you want I can show you how to derive the expectation also with your definition. But this procedure is already written in the link I posted you